# How to fill-in 2 different cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Does anybody know how to fill-in 2 different cells?[image]

For every cell I have specific class

```
import UIKit

class MindCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var textLabel1: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}

class StepsMind: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var number1Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var step1Label: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

But I don't know how to set up functions

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MindCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel1.text = "ABC"

        return cell
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier1 = "MindCell"
        let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier1, for: indexPath) as! StepsMind

        // Configure the cell...
        cell1.number1Label.text = "1"
        cell1.step1Label.text = "DEF"

        return cell1
        }
```

Xcode says that it's impossible to use 2 these functions at the same time. What I need to do?

Comment: How do you know which cell to use ? Different tableView or same ? Just in the same and unique `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, do and `if` test there to use one or the other.

Comment: Every cell has its own Identifier

Comment: Indeed, but they have an order, an indexPath. What's the logic behind when show a `MindCell` and when show a `StepsMind`?

Comment: First cell has a `MindCell` identifier, second cell has a `StepsMind` identifier

Comment: Then if (indexPath.row == 0){//do the MindCell stuff} else{//do the StepMind stuff}

Comment: Why don't you simply create both these cells for a single custom tableViewcell class and then load appropriate cell as per your requirement.

Comment: These cells are in different classes but they're in one tableView

Answer (score 0):

By looking at comments I assume you want alternate row types.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0
    {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MindCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel1.text = "ABC"

        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        let cellIdentifier1 = "MindCell"
        let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier1, for: indexPath) as! StepsMind

        // Configure the cell...
        cell1.number1Label.text = "1"
        cell1.step1Label.text = "DEF"

        return cell1

    }

}
```

Comment: There's one more problem with function `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }` 
If I set `return 1` it works properly but I see only one cell If I set `return 2` my program doesn't work

Comment: @IuriiUshakov if you have return 2, then you must also switch or do an `if else` for your `indexPath.section` to give the related row